# Bash doesn't create files in nested scripts

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, sed

When I run the first script that calls a second script *no files are created*.

However, when I call the second one **directly** with the same code as it appears on the *"echo"*, **it runs as expected**.'
Therefore, I really don't get what's wrong, as the code runs separately.

./first_script.sh 2 ../espn

First Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$2/$1" > format.temp
format=$(<format.temp)
format=$format"g.t*"
echo "./second_script.sh $format"
./second_script.sh $format
```

Here's the code of the second script (nested one):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$1*/discover/*data
for file in $files
do
    sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"/"foo"/' $file > $file\_2
    sed -i 's/"foo",//g' $file\_2
    sed -i 's/[0-9]g//gi' $file\_2
    sed -i 's/[^,.0-9]//g' $file\_2
done
```

***Note->*** 
The files are in the folders:

../espn/2g.tf/discover/

../espn/2g.tfidf/discover/

Comment: Try putting in back ticks like this : ` ./second_script.sh $format `

Comment: I just tried, it still didn't work. :/

Answer (score 1):

> Note-> The files are in the folders:
>
> ../espn/2g.tf/discover/
>
> ../espn/2g.tfidf/discover/

What does it mean?? first file in first directory and second in second??
I think your problem is with the path to access second file

try calling the second script using abslute path ('path begins from /')
if **espn** is in you home folder

```
~/espn/2g.tfidf/discover/second_script.sh $format
```

try adding echo statments in second file to make sure its accessible